# How to count rows and pull maximum in sqlite3 firefox

Tags: firefox, sqlite, firefox-addon

I am using SQLite Manager on Firefox. Can I use count and max commands together? I want to calculate the number of rows of data, and then pull the row with the maximum number of rows.
Example:

I have data with names and each class they took. I want to calculate the number of classes taken for each name, and then find the person with the most classes.

Right now, I am using:
select name, count(class) from tablename;

Is there a way I can use the max function in this to pull the person with the highest number of count(class)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `LIMIT` to obtain the name with the highest class count:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM tablename
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If this doesn't work, or you want an alternative, then doing a subquery is also possible:

```
SELECT MAX(t.nameCount)
FROM
(
    SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS nameCount
    FROM tablename
) t
```